# parallel.invoke behaving differently in Winform and Console Application

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing, console, backgroundworker

I recently built a prototype c# console application to read in measurements from four instruments in parallel(On the same `TimeStamp`), I used the parallel.invoke command to do so, The results were quite good every single time. Later i tried to implement the same concept in `Winforms` using `backgroundworker`. So in my `DoWork` i call this parallel.invoke to run the four functions to get readings, but the results are returned after so long and they are not on the same time stamp, I did try it without background worker but i have the same results. Any one has idea why parallel.invoke is behaving so?. That it works fine in console application and not in winform?. Also is there is a way to make sure that multiple `async procces` execution is run in parallel?. I am having a hard time understanding this, Please help me out here. Any comments would be appreciated!

**Update** : Sorry for the confusion , I did this before with parallel Invoke
             later i changed it to task but the behaviour is the same.

**Console Application**:

```
public static void funcc()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rawData3 = fmio.IO.Read(4 * numReadings);
        RawData3.Add(rawData3);
    }
}

public static void funcd()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rawData4 = fmio.IO.Read(4 * numReadings);
        RawData4.Add(rawData4);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Parallel.Invoke(() => { funcb(); }, () => { funcc(); }, () => { funca(); }, () => { funcd(); });       

    var factory = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None);

    Task t1 = factory.StartNew(funca);
    Task t2 = factory.StartNew(funcb);
    Task t3 = factory.StartNew(funcc);
    Task t4 = factory.StartNew(funcd);

    t1.Wait();
    t2.Wait();
    t3.Wait();
    t4.Wait();

    WriteToFile(); // Writes Result to the file
}
```

In my **Gui Application** I am am doing this in `backgroundWorker` I have the same readings functions as defined above that i am using in my GUI Application:

```
public static void funca()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rawData = fmio.IO.Read(4 * numReadings); // Getting Data in Byte Array
        RawData1.Add(rawData);                   // Putting it in ArrayList
    }
}

public static void funcb()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rawData2 = fmio.IO.Read(4 * numReadings);
        RawData2.Add(rawData2);
    }
}

private void btn_StartMeasurement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bwObj.IsBusy)
    {
        bw_Obj.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void bw_Obj_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Parallel.Invoke(() => { funcb(); }, () => { funcc(); }, () => { funca(); }, () => { funcd(); });

    var factoryA = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
    var time = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Task t1 = factoryA.StartNew(() => funca(Globls.numReadings, DMM));
    Task t2 = factoryA.StartNew(() => funcb(Globls.numReadings, DMM2));
    Task t3 = factoryA.StartNew(() => funcc(Globls.numReadings, DMM3));
    Task t4 = factoryA.StartNew(() => funcd(Globls.numReadings, DMM4));

    t1.Wait();
    t2.Wait();
    t3.Wait();
    t4.Wait();

    WriteToFile();
}
```

Comment: What hardware are you running this on? How many CPU cores do you have?

Comment: A simple code sample including the console code and the Windows Forms code would really help here.

Comment: I have included the code , hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle the issue like this: extract the working parallel-reading code in its own `static` class, then call it from both the console application *and* the winforms application, and see what happens. You should find yourself with something that either goes both ways, or doesn't work at all (since you're calling the same code).

Comment: I tried your sugesstion but the behaviour is still the same. I used synchronous I/O. Do you think that can cause a problem?. The reads are sequential in GUI application ( As i checked in the IO montier provided by the instrument software), but then again it's working fine in console application

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented many ways. If you're looking for executing what's in the bw_Obj_DoWork_1 section in parallel then I'd consider changing the btn_StartMeasurement_Click and dropping the BackgroundWorker.

```
private void btn_StartMeasurement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[]
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(funca),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(funcb),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(funcc),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(funcd)
        };
    Task writeTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (t) => writeToFile());
}
```

Or, you could create a method, I'll call it executeAndWrite, and use Threads or Tasks in btn_StartMeasurement_Click to start them:

```
private void btn_StartMeasurement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(executeAndWrite).Start();
}

private void executeAndWrite()
{
    Parallel.Invoke(funca, funcb, funcc, funcd);
    writeToFile();
}
```

I'd personally go with this option.